# Can't install private internet access

Tags: vpn

Followed this step by step: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/installer/download_installer_linux

Pia doesn't run after this command: 
./pia-v65-installer.sh

When I run it manually (with the mouse, click on run), Pia appears in Applications, but doesn't run.

I uninstalled it with rm -rf ~/.pia_manager/ and tried again. Both methods don't work yet again, and pia icon doesn't even appear in applications.

Any idea what's going on here?

This is what shows in Terminal when I try to install pia:

johan@johan-N76VB:~$ cd Downloads/
johan@johan-N76VB:~/Downloads$ tar -xzf pia-v65-linux.tar.gz
johan@johan-N76VB:~/Downloads$ ./pia-v65-installer.sh
Extracting files...
[sudo] password for johan: 
Installing dependencies...
Running: sudo apt-get install -y libxss1 libappindicator1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libappindicator1 is already the newest version (12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1).
libxss1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.2-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Installation complete!
johan@johan-N76VB:~/Downloads$

Comment: I've found this: https://helpdesk.privateinternetaccess.com/hc/en-us/articles/219438247-Installing-OpenVPN-PIA-on-Linux I don't know if it can help you anyhow.

Comment: Works fine for me, but doesn't have an app indicator. It shows up in trayer, a third party system tray for older app indicators. Did the install script give you any errors? What does the terminal say if you install again and run $HOME/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh

Comment: @ Jorge: that is for open vpn + pia

Comment: @ Michael Roberts: When I started my computer today, pia is in my applications folder. And when I double click it appears in my dock for a few seconds, and then it is gone. Nothing happens, I can't log in.

Comment: pia_nw: no process found
@ Michael Roberts This is what the terminal says:pia_nw: no process found
/home/johan/.pia_manager/pia_tray_bin/nw-linux-64/pia_nw: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: So kinda got the same issue. I've been able to use PIA thru openvpn using the CLI, (like this: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/11232/9078) but I have to run the commands every time i log in, restart etc. I dunno how to script and my linux knowledge is generally a bit limited.
Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Loki and got the same problem.
Apparently I solved using the [RoboLinux installation method](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/robolinux) as listed on PIA support site.
I'm connected to VPN right now. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: These instructions are also on the PIA website. It's one the first hits, if not the first, when you google installing PIA on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Install PIA as seen on the [site](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/installer/download_installer_linux).

Then edit pia_manager.desktop

```
sudo nano ~/.local/share/applications/pia_manager.desktop
```

And alter the line `Exec=/home/bats/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh` so it becomes like this:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /home/bats/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh
```

The icon will then appear on the panel.

Comment: Works on Elementary OS as well!

Answer (score 0):

This method works flawlessly for me...

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn